# Are there any known issues with Python parallel processing on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

This is perhaps not the right place to ask this question but I was unsure where else to go with it. My MSc dissertation is aimed at trying to use parallel computing to speed up stochastic biology simulations. I've written some standard format code for parallelisation of the simulations.

This code works on 7 out of 9 of my simulations but seems to get stuck when using `pool.map` on the other two.

Due to working form home etc and hardware/software constraints the only opperating systems I have available to me are Windows Subsystem for Linux and Windows powershell (which I've both tried). One thing my supervisor suggested is that this issue might be related to my operating system and that Windows might not be as good at parallelisation as Linux. But I'm struggling to find any hard evidence to back this up.

So is anyone aware of any papers or links to other posts that might provide a bit information about whether or not a Windows OS has issues with Python parallel processing?

Cheers

Comment: FWIW You can install a proper Operating System like Linux in VirtualBox under Windows without leaving the house. Or get an AWS free tier EC2 Linux box for nothing also without leaving the house.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about formal papers, but have had a lot of practical success using dask from [dask.org](http://dask.org)  So whether this is a good answer depends a lot on whether you just want results, or whether you're doing deep research.

I and my team began using dask about a year ago for parallelizing large `Pandas/numpy` jobs that were taking hours to run (if they didn't run out of memory).  Using dask, we were able to cut these down to minutes with successful (i.e., identical) results.

Lots of RAM still recommended, but the parallelization capabilities and process dashboard/feedback is a great step forward.